# AutoDesk Forge, Design Automation API, GET AppPackages: Who uploaded this AppPackage?

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk-designautomation

AutoDesk Team,

I recently did a 'GET AppPackages' to find out what AppPackages were installed on my App. I am a little concerned now though because there are four AppPackages installed and I was only expecting to see one.

I'd like to find additional metadata/logs regarding these other three AppPackages. Is there another 'GET' call that I can make (other than "GET Activities(‘:id’)/Operations.GetVersions") to retrieve this information and try to source who uploaded these AppPackages?

Thank you

Comment: Blatantly off-topic (this question has nothing to do with programming)

Answer (score -1):

These other packages are public AppPackages that other people have shared. Hopefully the description or the ID attribute will give you and idea what they are.